# Update the dataset of multiple AmCharts with a Single Dropdown Change Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I currently have 2 AMCharts on the same page and a single dropdown with values 2015,2016,2017,2018 in it.

I have followed this example to dynamically update the data in the bar chart
    http://www.amcharts.com/tips/dynamically-loading-chart-datasets/

I also have a Pie Chart and would like to update the data with the same drop down but I am not sure how to connect it so that it also updates at the same time.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Just expand the function that changes the dataset of the charts with your pie chart reference.

```
function setDataSet( dataset_url ) {
  // chart2 should be the reference to your pie chart
  chart.dataProvider = chart2.dataProvider = AmCharts.loadJSON( dataset_url );
  chart.validateData();
  chart2.validateData();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a working [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLeXee?editors=001).

Comment: I'm not sure how to incorporate this into my charting functions.  It is now only rendering one of the charts.The drop down is firing and updating the chart, but not chart1

Comment: Thank you so much, thats exactly what i'm looking for !

Comment: @Nimo1981 Glad I could help. I would appreciate if you could accept the answer then.