# changing data values in amcharts with drop down selection

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have the question regarding an already provided solution at
[Update the dataset of multiple AmCharts with a Single Dropdown Change Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34808991/update-the-dataset-of-multiple-amcharts-with-a-single-dropdown-change-event/53962402#53962402)

I needed the same solution for one of my tasks. I have downloaded and saved all the css,js, jquery and json dataset files in the same directory and changed the addresses of those in src tags in my html file. Also changed the address in index.js file for the default dataset json. But this does not work. drop down menu shows but both charts are not even showing. Can you please help. Here is the code in my index.htm file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Dynamically loading chart datasets</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="serial.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="none.js"></script>
<p class="selector">
<select onchange="setDataSet(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="data1.json">Data Set #1</option>
<option value="data2.json">Data Set #2</option>
<option value="data3.json">Data Set #3</option>
</select> &lt; Select a data set
</p>
<div id="barchart"></div>
<div id="piechart"></div>
<script src='jquery-1.11.2.min.js'></script>
<script  src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

in case the index.js code is also needed to be seen for any correction/amendment :

```
AmCharts.loadJSON = function(url) {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
request.open('GET', url, false);
request.send();

  return eval(request.responseText);
};
var bar_chart = AmCharts.makeChart("barchart", {
"type": "serial",
"theme": "none",
"dataProvider": AmCharts.loadJSON('data1.json'),
"valueAxes": [{
"gridColor":"#FFFFFF",
"gridAlpha": 0.2,
"dashLength": 0
}],
"gridAboveGraphs": true,
"startDuration": 1,
"graphs": [{
"balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
"fillAlphas": 0.8,
"lineAlpha": 0.2,
"type": "column",
"valueField": "visits"      
}],
"chartCursor": {
"categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
"cursorAlpha": 0,
"zoomable": false
},
"categoryField": "country",
"categoryAxis": {
"gridPosition": "start",
"gridAlpha": 0,
"tickPosition":"start",
"tickLength":20
}
});
var pie_chart = AmCharts.makeChart("piechart", {
"type": "pie",
"theme": "light",
"dataProvider": AmCharts.loadJSON('data1.json'),
"valueField": "visits",
"titleField": "country",
"balloon":{
"fixedPosition":true
}
});
function setDataSet( dataset_url ) {
bar_chart.dataProvider = pie_chart.dataProvider =         
AmCharts.loadJSON(dataset_url);
bar_chart.validateData();
pie_chart.validateData();
}
```

Comment: anyone, any solution? i have downloaded the expample from codepen but charts do not appear

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Are you running it on a local webserver or are you just opening index.html directly (does it say `file://` in your browser or `http://`)? AJAX requests tend to not work if you're running it over `file://` due to browser security restrictions.

Comment: Is there a way out to get it working as a static html file without hosting on webserver

Comment: Not with AJAX. As I mentioned before, AJAX won't work without a server due to browser restrictions. Some browsers let you override this but it's not recommended as it is unsafe. [Here's a guide](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/) for Chrome. Alternatively, you can hard code the data in the HTML file itself as separate arrays and change the code to switch which array you want to use instead of using loadJSON.

Comment: @xorspark Thank you for your assistance so far. I've tried the guide but it seems unpractical solution for me. Hard coded data array will definitely work for my project but due to very limited programming knowledge and skills, i am unable to do it without AJAX/loading JSON.

Comment: i've found one example which works perfectly in a static html file but that is using zingcharts instead of amcharts. https://codepen.io/derekfletes/pen/xLmqZE. Would really appreciate if the same could be done using AMcharts (data arrays/values to be changed in AMchart using drop down menus in static html file)

Comment: Any one  on how to do this in static HTML file?