# How to show 2-3 AMcharts in single static HTML

Tags: javascript, amcharts

For a project, i need to display three different types of AMcharts (pie, bar, line) in a single html static page (not hosted on server) and change the dataset of all of these three with a select menu option.

For example menu options can be jan, feb, mar, apr and data for pie chart can be product a, b, c with values 5,10,20 respectively. Data for bar chart can be defect x, y, x with values 300,400, 260. Similarly line chart will be having some different data set. All three charts will be presented side by side and equal in size.

All the data will be barcoded inside html/javascript without any need to connect with any database or a server. AMcharts js files will also be stored in the local pc as all of this task is to run offline. I'll really appreciate if some simple example code could be written. Thank you all

Comment: StackOverflow won't write the code for you. I suggest doing some research and trying this yourself. When you get stuck on a more specific problem during your journey, come back and ask that with the proper code you wrote to accompany it.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thanks for your reply. My intention is not to get the whole code written by StackOverflue, instead, I wanted some example code already written (if any). I am stuck here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962755/changing-data-values-in-amcharts-with-drop-down-selection would really appreciate if you could help out

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding a starter for you below. You can copy this HTML and save on a HTML file. You should be able to run it from there.

All amCharts files are loading from CDN so you don't need to copy its content.

Each chart uses its own ID and its code is enclosed in a function so you don't have to be creative with variable names.

Now the chart code part I'm leaving with you. Have fun!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>amCharts V4 Example - multiple charts</title>
    
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
        background-color: #ffffff;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .chart {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        height: 100vh;
        max-height: 600px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Add first chart container -->
    <div id="chart-1" class="chart"></div>

    <!-- Add second chart container -->
    <div id="chart-2" class="chart"></div>

    <!-- Add third chart container -->
    <div id="chart-3" class="chart"></div>

    <!-- Add chart dependencies from CDN -->
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

    <!-- Add the charts -->
    <script>
        // Set the theme
        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

        // Enclose the code for chart-1
        (function () {

            var chart = am4core.create("chart-1", am4charts.PieChart);

            // Add data
            chart.data = [{
                "country": "Lithuania",
                "litres": 501.9
            }, {
                "country": "Czech Republic",
                "litres": 301.9
            }, {
                "country": "Ireland",
                "litres": 201.1
            }, {
                "country": "Germany",
                "litres": 165.8
            }, {
                "country": "Australia",
                "litres": 139.9
            }, {
                "country": "Austria",
                "litres": 128.3
            }, {
                "country": "UK",
                "litres": 99
            }, {
                "country": "Belgium",
                "litres": 60
            }, {
                "country": "The Netherlands",
                "litres": 50
            }];

            // The chart code comes here

        })();

        // Enclose the code for chart-2
        (function () {

            var chart = am4core.create("chart-2", am4charts.PieChart);

            // The chart code comes here

        })();

        // Enclose the code for chart-3
        (function () {

            var chart = am4core.create("chart-3", am4charts.PieChart);

            // The chart code comes here

        })();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing me a starter. i'll come back with integrating my data into it. Thanks